# Check document in MarkLogic Collection Using .Net Xcc

Tags: marklogic

How to check whether a document exists in a collection in MarkLogic Database using .Net XCC?

Answer (score 2):

If performance is important, you might want to avoid the fragment fetch for `xdmp:document-get-collections`. This is possible if you have the URI lexicon enabled.

```
exists(
  cts:uris(
    (), (),
    cts:and-query(
      (cts:document-query($document-uri),
       cts:collection-query($collection-uri)))))
```

This asks the URI lexicon if there are any document uris that match the specified collection URI and document URI.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the basics of `XCC`, use an `AdHoc` Query 
http://docs.marklogic.com/6.0/javadoc/xcc/com/marklogic/xcc/AdhocQuery.html

The simpliest way I know is to use

```
  xdmp:document-get-collections()
```

http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-get-collections

So you can build an ad-hoc query like this:

```
xdmp:document-get-collections("doc.xml") = "collection"
```

Note the "=" is a set equals

The result is a boolean

If you are concerned about XQuery Injection (i.e. you are not in total control of the string "doc.xml" you should use an external parameter.

```
declare variable $doc external ;
declare variable $collection external ;
xdmp:document-get-collections($doc) = $collection
```

Then pass the value of parameter "`doc`" and "`collection:`" as an external variables to the query.

Comment: Hi, Thank for your information.Let me explain my Requirement. I have to insert documents using XCC into Marklogic database. I have completed this Part. While inserting  i have used collection to identify / Classify my documents. Here My Issue is when the same insert Process comes, i have to check for duplication of document using the KEY (say <ID>) in the MarkLogic database. Now I want to get the documents from the Collection and check for duplication.
How to get the Documents List of a Collection using .Net XCC.
Thanks